# Azure SQL database PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that loops through each user database in Azure SQL server supplied as a parameter and enable the TDE and return the status.

How can I create a PowerShell script for that?  Can you show me some examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt619404.aspx) cmdlet

Comment: Thanks ,but How can I loop through each database one at the time to execute Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption  in powershell script?

Comment: I have something like this so far to loop though azure sql user databases in a server,,,, I am not sure how to loop through databases one at the time 
Login-AzureRMAccount

$AzureSQLServer = Get-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName
$AzureSQLdatabases =Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "test" -ServerName $AzureSQLServer 
$AzureSQLDatabase= ?? singledatabe
# loop through each  user databases  in Azure SQL Server
 foreach ($AzureSQLDatabase in $AzureSQLdatabases)  
 {  
   
  
    Set-AzureRMSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption -State 'Enabled' 
 }

Comment: Do you successfully get the $AzureSQLdatabases variable? If so, then the only thing I see missing is to specify the DB to operate on. delete the line where you have `$AzureSQLDatabase= ?? singledatabe` and in the line inside the loop, pipe the current DB to the cmdlet like so `$AzureSQLDatabase | Set-AzureRMSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption -State Enabled`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each database this way: [Azure PowerShell - Extracting Azure SQL Database information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387664/azure-powershell-extracting-azure-sql-database-information)

Then change the code and adapt it to TDE.